# Class and case statements -- why doesn't this evaluate as expected?

Tags: ruby

```
k = Integer
case k
  when Integer
    "HI"
  else "BYE"
end
```

In ruby 1.8, this evaluates to `"BYE"`. I would anticipate it to evaluate to `"HI"` as `Integer == Integer` evaluates to `true`. What operator does the `when` statement use? Is there something I'm missing??

Answer (score 4):

`case` expressions use the `===` operator of the object in the `when` clause. So it evaluates to `Integer === k`. The tricky thing here is that `Class#===` is essentially implemented this way:

```
class Class
  def ===(obj)
    obj.kind_of? self
  end
end
```

This is meant for methods that can accept many classes in the same parameter, so it's easy to test the argument's type and treat it appropriately. But as you can see, it's not an identity test. So it's testing whether Integer is an instance of Integer — which it isn't (it's an instance of Class).

Depending on your exact use case, a Hash might be closer to what you want.

Comment: Excellent explanation! It doesn't help me find a solution necessarily, but it does explain what is happening.